# Arch hangs on [OK] Reached Target Graphical Interface

Tags: arch-linux, boot, xorg, gnome

I have just installed Arch Linux, and pacmaned the packages gnome and xorg. I can run the startx command just fine, but when I make gdm.service run at startup, Arch completely freezes, with just the linux kernel boot screen and a cursor in the center of the screen. I am not running VirtualBox, and I am installing alongside Ubuntu, if that helps.
I am running Arch on a 10 year old craptop.

Edit: I have installed SDDM, but cannot log in as there are no profiles to log in to.

Thanks!

Comment: If you have a high-end Nvidia Graphics you may need additional boot parameters until the Nvidia proprietary drivers are installed.

Comment: Gnome/GDM runs wayland by default, not X.